# Word for property such that any object which possesses it is the only object which possesses it?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

Suppose that I have a property such that any object which possesses it is the only object which possesses it. For example we might suppose that the property of "being Sally's partner" is such a property as Sally is a monogamist.

Is there a name for such a property?

I thought it might be called a definite description but the Stanford Encyclopedia article on descriptions http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descriptions claims that a definite description is a *sentence* not a property- so a sentence like "John is Sally's partner" is a definite description.

Comment: This seems to be largely an English question rather than necessarily a philosophy question. Can you expand on why this is a philosophy question? (The words "monopoly" and "singular" come to mind btw).

Comment: If I asked the question- "Is there a word for a sentence of the form "The F is G" then the answer would be that such a sentence is called a definite description so this question falls under the purview of philosophy (as well as linguistics) and is thus (I assume) a valid question for this forum. How can I tell before receiving an answer that such properties haven't been studied by philosophers (of language)?

Comment: But having said that I would welcome it if you are able to advise me on how to rephrase my question more constructively as this is the first question I have asked on this forum!

Comment: Might "exclusive" meet your needs?

Comment: As in, we could say the property of being Sally's partner is an exclusive property?

Comment: Unique? As in 2 is the unique even prime. The name for the property would be "uniquely characterizing." As in, the property of being an even prime uniquely characterizes the number 2. This is a common usage in math.

Comment: Just googled it and got some positive results. Thanks. Looks like I should have posted this in maths stackexchange after all. I got thrown by the fact that definite descriptions are so similar to what I was after. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @BernardWojcik Just a comment about definite descriptions. The bit you wrote about it is wrong. Definite descriptions are definitely *not sentences* (however they might be analyzed as sentences in disguise (e.g. by Russell), but that is another matter). Sentences can be true or false, while definite descriptions cannot. They are not properties either. A definite description is primarily used *to refer*, like a name. "Sally's partner" is a definite description, it is used to refer to the person who is Sally's partner, just like the name "John".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old philosophical term: the latin [haecceitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haecceity):

> which translates as "thisness", and denotes the discrete qualities, properties or characteristics of a thing which make it a particular thing. *Haecceity* is a person or object's "thisness", the individualising difference between the concept "a man" and the (individual) concept "Socrates" (a specific person).
>
> Haecceity is a literal translation of the equivalent term in Aristotle's Greek *to ti esti* or "the what (it) is."

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clearly a definite description. An example of another one is "The tree closest to The White House on Jan 1, 2016." It picks out a unique thing which may or may not have been given a name.

It is not the case that definite descriptions are sentences.